# Why is running opendir, readdir, stat so slow compared to the Windows dir command?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, scripting, perl

I have a Perl script that is using `opendir` to read the contents of a directory:

```
opendir ( DIR, $path ) or next;
    while (my $file = readdir DIR) {
```

Then I'm doing:

- `-s $file` to get the size of each file
- `(stat($file))[9]` to get the modified time of each file

I'm running this from a Windows machine and accessing a Samba share on Ubuntu 14.04.

This is all working fine but the process seems to run very slow compared to when I run a `dir` listing on the same folder.

Does anyone know why using `opendir` takes so much longer than a `dir` listing and if there's any way I can change my script to speed it up?

Comment: As long as you're calling `stat`, retrieve the file size with `(stat($file))[7]`,

Comment: @mob can you tell me the difference between using stat and -s ? Thanks

Comment: @A-Kay The file test operators like `-s` actually make a `stat` system call behind the scenes, so if you call `-s` followed by `stat`, you're making two system calls when only one is necessary.

Comment: [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#stat) says the following about `stat`: "On Win32 `stat()` needs to open the file to determine the link count and update attributes that may have been changed through hard links. Setting `${^WIN32_SLOPPY_STAT}` to a true value speeds up `stat()` by not performing this operation." Try that, plus mob's suggestion, and see if it speeds things up. I imagine opening files on the Samba share is time consuming.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thanks for that - using WIN32_SLOPPY_STAT really sped things up for me. Thanks mob

Comment: @A-Kay Great! I've moved my comment to an answer in case somebody has the same issue in the future.

Comment: `WIN32_SLOPPY_STAT` has now been removed from Perl 5.34.0 since the UCRT implementation, always opens the specified file. Just a late FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#stat):

> On Win32 `stat()` needs to open the file to determine the link count and update attributes that may have been changed through hard links. Setting `${^WIN32_SLOPPY_STAT}` to a true value speeds up `stat()` by not performing this operation.

Since the files you're accessing are on a Samba share, opening them is probably fairly time consuming. Also, `-s` makes a `stat` system call behind the scenes, so calling `-s` followed by `stat` is wasteful.

The following should be faster:

```
local ${^WIN32_SLOPPY_STAT} = 1;

opendir my $dh, $path or die "Failed to opendir '$path': $!";

while (my $file = readdir $dh) {
    my ($size, $mtime) = (stat $file)[7, 9];

    say join "\t", $file, $size, $mtime;
}
```

Comment: What about `-s $file` followed by `-M _`? According to the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) the `-M _` won't do a 2nd `stat()` but use the last `stat`'s results, i.e. only _one_ call to `stat` too.

Comment: @PerlDog That only makes one `stat` call, but would give a different result. `-M` returns the script start time *minus* file mtime, in days; `stat` returns the mtime in epoch seconds.

Comment: True, but adding `$^T` would not harm.

Comment: @PerlDog Sure, you could add a bunch of logic to convert the result of `-M` from days to seconds and subtract that from `$^T`, but why would you rather do that than a single `stat`???

Comment: LOL, ok, you won. :-) Just wanted to tell that using the `_` as a filehandle/name avoids add'l calls to `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Dir will be much faster as it is binary code that I suspect is very optimized, so so it can retrieve and format the information quickly.

In your script it seems you are doing several calls which have to be interpreted, one for the time and another for the size.  Even if the lower calls  in Perl are binary code, to get the information it probably has to go through several layers.  You could reduce the number of calls by @mob suggestion by saving the returned values of stat and accessing the parts you need.  For example:

```
@items = stat($file);
$size = $items[7];
$modified = $items[9];
```

which would save one of the calls and possibly speed up the script.

If you want all of the files, you might consider doing a system call to do a directory command and redirect the output to a file, after which you can parse the file to get the information of times and size.  This may be a bit faster depending on the amount of files.  ( /4 will be a 4 digit year, /t:w will be when it was last written/modified and /c will get rid of the commas in the size)

```
system("dir /4 /t:w /-c $path > tempList.txt");
```

Then open and parse redirected file for the information you desire.

```
open my $in,"tempList.txt" die "Unable to open file tempList.txt";
my @lines = <$in>;
close($in);
chomp(@lines);

foreach ( @lines ) 
{
  next if ( ! ( m/^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s+ ); # Not a line with a file
  @parts = split('\s+');
  # Get the parts you need (time and size, where you may have to some other
  # work to get it in the desired format
  #.....
}
```

It may be possible to add regex to do matching and pull out items as you need them when testing if you want to process the line.  That might save some time and effort as well.

Comment: Thanks @Glenn. The main problem here is that dir does not give me seconds so I cannot compare it to the current epoch that I'm already getting from the stat. I found a workaround that gives me seconds by using: `forfiles /c "cmd /c echo @file @ftime"` however this does not work on UNC paths (which mine are). Is using dir going to be my only way forward? I'm seeing about a 20x speed decrease using my current method over dir

Comment: Your very welcome @A-Kay.  If you need to use UNC paths, I would look up the net command  where you would use net subcommand to mount a UNC path as a drive.  This might be helpful for what you are trying to achieve.  If you need the speed of dir, is is possible that just using minutes for comparisons would be enough granularity for your efforts?

Comment: @Glenn: Wouldn't this also work to get the files one file per line? `@filelist=\`ls -1\` `  I simply find it easier to loop through an array especially when I have to use the debugger to see what's in the array.

Comment: @Bulrush: That would work if the number of files was not large and if the command was @filelist = `dir /4 /t:w /-c $path` as it is a windows machine.  There would be additional parsing for each line.  It might be a bit faster as you are correct that you would not have to read from a file.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me instead of flaming me. So opendir() works on all operating systems and is the preferred method? Since I only work on Linux that's why I used the format I did.

Comment: @Glenn I'd rather not map a drive. I'm actually only calling -s and stat[9] some of the time - I actually thought that calling [9] specifically would be faster than performing a stat on the file and pulling out what I need - is that the case? Usually I only do one at a time so it probably won't save a lot but on the ones that do overlap this will save me - which is handy as I'm dealing with millions of files. so thanks!